# Media queries and browser resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

on my Website:  i used some `@media` queries to get different backgrounds for different solutions. My problem now is, that if you drag the window in 1080p high but for example just 1024 with you see white borders on top and bottom.

That is normal since the picture was designed for 768p hight so its not the problem.

Since i didn't add a container because it was to hard for me i decided to do the container on my background picture. Due to that fact i need to use the background "fixed" so it scales with the responsive design of the website and keeps the match.

Now my question is, is there a way to fix the white stripe problem? Its not that of a big deal since you don't see them if you resolution fits but i wouldn't like to do for example 1024x1200 pictures just to match with the heigh. Im pretty sure a picture like that will look poor on a 1024x768 screen.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
/* 1680x1050 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1601px) and (max-width : 1680px) {
    /* Styles */
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 1.42857;
        background: #f4f5f7 url('http://evoxity.net/themes/default-bootstrap/img/background/1680x1050.jpg');
        margin: 0;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        -moz-background-size:cover;
        background-size:fixed;
        overflow: auto;
        background-position:center;
        background-attachment:fixed;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense: `-moz-background-size:cover; background-size:fixed;`. Sounds like the latter should also be `cover`.

Comment: I also tryed 

`background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;`
But then the picture isnt fixed so the container doesnt match everytime with the website.

Comment: Perhaps post a live link, as we can only guess otherwise.